# ZenML Dag didn't show up in Airflow UI

Tags: airflow

I was trying out ZenML, it said it can convert my .py pipeline into airflow DAG.
I followed every step here: https://docs.zenml.io/guides/low-level-api/chapter-7, all succeeded

My pipeline runs well locally, but why can't see this DAG created on airflow UI? The UI is totally empty....

The problem seems that, ZenML will copy my .py pipeline wrote in ZenML way, and expect it can run in airflow... In my case this won't work. Does anyone know how can I let ZenML run my code through airflow successfully?

Here's my ZenML .py code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score

from zenml.pipelines import pipeline
from zenml.steps import step
from zenml.steps.step_output import Output
from zenml.steps.base_step_config import BaseStepConfig

class pipeline_config(BaseStepConfig):
    """
    Params used in the pipeline
    """
    label: str = 'species'

@step
def split_data(config: pipeline_config) -> Output(
    X=pd.DataFrame, y=pd.DataFrame
):
    path_to_csv = os.path.join('~/airflow/data', 'leaf.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
    label = config.label

    y = df[[label]]
    X = df.drop(label, axis=1)

    return X, y


@step
def train_evaltor(
    config: pipeline_config,
    X: pd.DataFrame,
    y: pd.DataFrame
) -> float:
    y = y[config.label]

    folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=10)
    lgbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='multiclass', random_state=10)
    metrics_lst = []

    for train_idx, val_idx in folds.split(X, y):
        X_train, y_train = X.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[train_idx]
        X_val, y_val = X.iloc[val_idx], y.iloc[val_idx]

        lgbm.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = lgbm.predict(X_val)

        cv_balanced_accuracy = balanced_accuracy_score(y_val, y_pred)
        metrics_lst.append(cv_balanced_accuracy)

    avg_performance = np.mean(metrics_lst)
    print(f"Avg Performance: {avg_performance}")

    return avg_performance


@pipeline
def super_mini_pipeline(
    data_spliter,
    train_evaltor
):
    X, y = data_spliter()
    train_evaltor(X=X, y=y)


# run the pipeline
pipeline = super_mini_pipeline(data_spliter=split_data(),
                                train_evaltor=train_evaltor())
pipeline.run()
```

Comment: I think you need to also spin airflow up using `zenml orchestrator up`. Have you do that as a pre requisite? P.S Could you also add the `zenml` tag on the question for greater visibility :-)

Comment: I did that, and it was showing airflow was up....

Comment: I've added a ticket in the system and we'll try to replicate your pipeline steps tomorrow and get back on this thread. In the meanwhile feel free to join the Slack to coordinate directly (https://zenml.io/slack-invite)

Comment: Perfect! I just joined the chat. Look forward to hearing the good news!

Comment: And here's a similar airflow code worked for me: https://github.com/lady-h-world/My_Garden/blob/main/code/garden_market/airflow_pipeline/super_mini_pipeline.py, this was written by myself, I was expecting ZenML could do this for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it worked! See picture below:

[image]

The reason is that the words `airflow` and `dag` have to be in the airflow if `safe_mode` is on (which it is by default). This is airflow specific logic can be in the airflow codebase.

So all I did was change the last few lines:

```
# run the pipeline airflow
pipeline = super_mini_pipeline(data_spliter=split_data(),
                                train_evaltor=train_evaltor())
DAG = pipeline.run()
```

You can also change the `airflow.cfg` file and turn safe mode off:

In `$HOME/.config/zenml/airflow_root/<UUID>/airflow.cfg`

```
# When discovering DAGs, ignore any files that don't contain the strings ``DAG`` and ``airflow``.
dag_discovery_safe_mode = False
```

Edit:
There might be another reason: Airflow DAG discovery also relies on the DAG being the globals() so maybe we needed to catch it with `DAG = pipeline.run()`. So in any case, it works!

Comment: Perfect! Perfect! Works for me now! Thank you very much Hamza! BTW, do you know how can I set the time interval of a pipeline? Or is there any document? Thank you!

Comment: Yes do: `zenml orchestrator register airflow_orchestrator_2 airflow --schedule_interval_minutes=X`. X is the minutes. Then you can create another stack as well with that orchestrator.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much Hamza!